# Difference between return values of scanf("%s", str) and scanf("%[^\n]s", str)

Tags: c

```
while(scanf("%s",a))
{
     if(a[0]=='#')
         break;
     nextpermutation(a);
}
```

This while loop perfectly works for `scanf("%s", a)`
but if I put `scanf("%[^\n]s", a)` in the while it just runs for one time.
I checked the return value of both scanf and they were the same still.
I didn't get why this is happening...

Comment: `%s` discards leading whitespace, `%[set]` does not. On the first call, you read up to, but not including, `\n` character, which remains in the stream. On the second call, `%[^\n]` cannot retrieve any character, as the very first one is `\n`.

Comment: try `" %99[^\n]"` -- note the space at the start of the string (to ignore whitespace) and the limit of 99 characters (to not overflow the buffer).

Comment: Note that in `"%[^\n]s"`, the `s` is not part of the scan-set and never matches the newline left by the scan-set.  It is simply wrong (though you'll often not spot the difference unless there's another conversion specification after that in the same format string).

Comment: the function: `scanf()` can also return EOF. and if that occurs, the posted  loop will continue forever.  also need to avoid input buffer overflow.  Suggest something like: `maxChar = sizeof(a) -1; while( 1 == scanf("%" maxChar "s",a) )`

Answer (score 4):

The battle of two losers: `"%s"` vs. `"%[^\n]s"`:

Both specifiers are *bad* and do not belong in robust code.  Neither limits user input and can easily overrun the destination buffer.

The `s` in `"%[^\n]s"` serves no purpose.  [@Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693495/difference-between-return-values-of-scanf-s-and-scanf-ns/40695400#comment68620014_40693495). So `"%[^\n]"` is reviewed following - still that is bad.

`"%s"` consumes leading white-space.  `"%[^\n]"` does not [@Igor Tandetnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40693495/difference-between-return-values-of-scanf-s-and-scanf-ns#comment68617261_40693495)

`"%[^\n]"` reads *nothing* if the leading character is a `'\n'`, leaving `a` unchanged or rarely in an unknown state.

`"%[^\n]"` reads all characters in except `'\n'`.

`"%s"` reads all leading white-space, discards them, then reads and saves all non-white-spaces.

---

Better to use `fgets()` to read a *line* of user input and then parse it.

Example: to read a line of input, including spaces:

```
char a[100];
if (fgets(a, sizeof a, stdin) == NULL) Handle_EOF_or_Error();

// if the potential trailing \n is not wanted
a[strcspn(a, "\n")] = '\0';
```

Answer (score 2):

What is that `s` doing there in `%[^\n]s`?

Your `scanf("%[^\n]s")` contains *two* format specifiers in its format string: `%[^\n]` followed by a lone `s`. This will require the input stream to contain `s` after the sequence matched by `%[^\n]`. This is, of course, is not very close in behavior to plain `%s`. Matching sequences for these formats will be very different for that reason alone.

Note that `[]` is not a modifier for `%s` format, as you seem to incorrectly believe. `[]` in `scanf` is a self-sufficient format specifier. Did you mean just `%[^\n]` by any chance instead of `%[^\n]s`?

Comment: Strangely, when I used `scanf("%[a-z]s", command)`  I still read "move" into command without error? I tested this on Visual Studio 2019, written in a `.c` file.

Comment: @Rainning That's not remarkable at all. First `scanf` successfully reads the string for the `%[]` format and stores it in `command`, then it stumbles upon that extra `s` and aborts. But by that moment the `command` is already read. So the whole thing appears to "work". Try adding extra formats and arguments after that `s` and you'll see that none of them work, because `scanf` aborts at that `s` (unless there is a matching `s` in the input).

Comment: So how to match exactly the regular expression `[a-z]s` into a single variable by `scanf`?

Comment: @Rainning: Firstly, it is not a regular expression. The language of `scanf` format strings is different (and very simplistic). Secondly, only the part that matches the `%` format specifier (in your case - `%[a-z]`) is saved into the recipient variable. And finally, it is not possible to create a string that would properly match the whole `%[a-z]s` format, because the `%[a-z]` part will consume all lowercase letters and there will be nothing left to match that trailing `s`.

Comment: OK, I got what you meant, so I have to create a O(n) for loop and check whether a word ends with `s`, right?

Comment: @Rainning: I'm not sure I understand what problem you are trying to solve. Why are you even considering `"%[a-z]s"`? What is your original objective?

Comment: Oh, sorry for my bad grammar. I meant I just wanted to read words ended with `s`, I thought this can be done by `scanf` itself.